# C# Paint a Panel to surround its Location value

Tags: c#, panel, paint

I'm making a TrackBar-like User Control.

The user can click on a Panel and drag it to change the value of `int SelectedMin`.

I want to draw the `SelectedMin` panel to surround the mouse as I drag instead of starting at the mouse. In other terms, I want the center of the panel to appear at my `SelectedMin` value instead of the left side of the panel at `SelectedMin`.

I believe this should be working with a line in my `ToolboxCustomTrackBar_Paint()` method:

```
minPanel.Location = new Point((SelectedMin * Width / (Max - Min)) - PanelWidth/2, LabelHeight);
```

The program starts correctly, with only half of the panel originally displaying, indicating that the `... - PanelWidth/2` is working, but then when I click on the panel to drag it, it centers the left of the panel where my mouse cursor is.

---

The top image is what currently happens. The bottom image is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

---

Related code:

```
    private int min = 0;
    private int max = 1000;
    private int selectedMin = 200;
    private int labelWidth = 0;
    private int labelHeight = 200;
    private int panelWidth = 10;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return min; }
        set { min = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int Max
    {
        get { return max; }
        set { max = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int SelectedMin
    {
        get { return selectedMin; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= Min && value <= Max)
            {
                selectedMin = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
    public int LabelWidth
    {
        get { return labelWidth; }
        set { labelWidth = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int LabelHeight
    {
        get { return labelHeight; }
        set { labelHeight = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int PanelWidth
    {
        get { return panelWidth; }
        set { panelWidth = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    public ToolboxCustomTrackBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

        selectionWidth = (Max - Min) / Width;

        minLabel.Text = "0";
        LabelWidth = minLabel.Width;
    }

    private void ToolboxCustomTrackBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var panel in panels)
        {
            panel.Height = Height - LabelHeight;

            if (panel != backdropPanel)
            {
                panel.Width = PanelWidth;
            }
        }

        minPanel.Location = new Point((SelectedMin * Width / (Max - Min)) - PanelWidth/2, LabelHeight);
    }

    private void minPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            SelectedMin += Min + e.X * (Max - Min) / Width;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just created a trackbar on myself and it seems to work:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestProjectWinforms
{
    public partial class TrackBar : UserControl
    {
        private int _CurrentValue;
        private bool _IsDragging;
        private int _MaximumValue;
        private int _MinimumValue;

        public TrackBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TrackColor = Color.Red;
            TrackWidth = 10;
            MinimumValue = 0;
            MaximumValue = 10000;
            CurrentValue = 3000;
            HotTrackEnabled = true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CurrentValueChanged;

        public int CurrentValue
        {
            get => _CurrentValue;
            set
            {
                _CurrentValue = value;
                ValidateCurrentValue();
                Invalidate();
                RaiseEvent(CurrentValueChanged);
            }
        }

        public bool HotTrackEnabled { get; set; }

        public int MaximumValue
        {
            get => _MaximumValue;
            set
            {
                _MaximumValue = value;

                if (_MaximumValue < _MinimumValue)
                    _MaximumValue = _MinimumValue;

                ValidateCurrentValue();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int MinimumValue
        {
            get => _MinimumValue;
            set
            {
                _MinimumValue = value;

                if (_MinimumValue > _MaximumValue)
                    _MinimumValue = _MaximumValue;

                ValidateCurrentValue();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public Color TrackColor { get; set; }

        public int TrackWidth { get; set; }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);

            if (HotTrackEnabled)
                _IsDragging = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (_IsDragging)
            {
                UpdateCurrentValueFromPosition(e.X);
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            _IsDragging = false;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(TrackColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, CreateRectangle());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            Invalidate();
        }

        private RectangleF CreateRectangle()
        {
            var position = GetRectanglePosition();
            var rectangle = new RectangleF(position, 0, TrackWidth, Height);
            return rectangle;
        }

        private float GetRectanglePosition()
        {
            var range = _MaximumValue - _MinimumValue;
            var value = _CurrentValue - _MinimumValue;
            var percentage = (float)value * 100 / range;
            var position = percentage * Width / 100;

            return position - (float)TrackWidth / 2;
        }

        private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler handler)
        {
            handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void UpdateCurrentValueFromPosition(float x)
        {
            var percentage = x * 100 / Width;
            var range = _MaximumValue - _MinimumValue;
            var rawValue = percentage * range / 100;
            var value = rawValue + _MinimumValue;

            CurrentValue = (int)Math.Round(value);
        }

        private void ValidateCurrentValue()
        {
            if (_CurrentValue < _MinimumValue)
                _CurrentValue = _MinimumValue;

            if (_CurrentValue > _MaximumValue)
                _CurrentValue = _MaximumValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It seems like we're doing the same thing. I'm starting to wonder if maybe it's something to do with the `Panel`, since you (and many others) seem to prefer drawing rectangles.

How come you have two different functions for calculating `GetRectanglePosition()` and `UpdateCurrentValueFromPosition()` when they seem to do the same thing?  Also, I'm not familiar with `base.Method(e)`, what is it?

Comment: The two methods are complementary. `GetRectanglePosition()` takes the current value and calculates the x position in pixel for the rectangle. With `UpdateCurrentValueFromPosition()` I'll take the current mouse position (when the user drags the rectangle) and calculate the current value in the range.

Comment: The `base.Method(e)` is needed, cause I overwrite the existing methods in the class. But I don't like to replace these methods. Instead I'd like to do only some additional stuff. Therefore I have to call the base method to let the default behaviour run and afterwards do my additional things. If you like to dig deeper you should search for `virtual override c#`. It's a common technique in object oriented programming.